# Sqoop through JAVA API

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

We are trying to sqoop data from mysql to HDFS. When we run the code the data gets stored in local file system. We want the data to be in HDFS. Can any one suggest us with the following code?

```
    SqoopOptions options = new SqoopOptions();
    options.setConnectString("jdbc:mysql:hostname/db_name");
    options.setUsername("user");
    options.setPassword("pass");
    options.setTableName("table");
    options.setDirectMode(true);
    options.setNumMappers(4);  
    options.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    options.setSqlQuery("select * from table");
    options.setWhereClause("value > 15.0");
    options.setTargetDir("output");
    options.doHiveImport();
    System.out.println();
    int ret=new ImportTool().run(options);
    System.out.println(ret);
```

Comment: How are you running the code?

Answer (score 0):

I ran the same program in hdfs and got the output :)

Answer (score 0):

Here the issue is with `options.setTargetDir("output");`
You are not specifying a qualifying HDFS path. If you change "output" with a valid HDFS path, you should be able to run the code from anywhere and still get a proper result.